# How to add a range of items to an IList?

Tags: c#, list, collections, addrange

There is no `AddRange()` method for `IList<T>`.

How can I add a list of items to an `IList<T>` without iterating through the items and using the `Add()` method?

Answer (score 75, accepted):

`AddRange` is defined on `List<T>`, not the interface.

You can declare the variable as `List<T>` instead of `IList<T>` or cast it to `List<T>` in order to gain access to `AddRange`.

```
((List<myType>)myIList).AddRange(anotherList);
```

This is not good practice (see comments below), as an `IList<T>` might *not* be a `List<T>`, but some other type that implemented the interface and may very well not have an `AddRange` method - in such a case, you will only find out when your code throws an exception at runtime.

So, unless you know for certain that the type is indeed a `List<T>`, you shouldn't try to use `AddRange`.

One way to do so is by testing the type with the [is](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/operators/type-testing-and-cast#is-operator) or [as](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/operators/type-testing-and-cast#as-operator) operators (since C# 7).

```
if(myIList is List<T>)
{
   // can cast and AddRange
}
else
{
   // iterate with Add
}
```

Comment: Does this really accomplish anything? Doesn't `AddRange` just loop anyway?

Comment: as it's a property of a model (being used with EF ) which way is preferred ?

Comment: @JonB - Sure, as do all the LINQ options (`Concat`, for example). This is just a succinct way of doing the same thing.

Comment: @mohsen.d - If the type is generated, you don't want to change the generated code (as it is liable to be overwritten). Either cast or use LINQ `Concat`, as @Self_Taught_Programmer [answered](http://stackoverflow.com/a/13158155/1583).

Comment: @Oded : no I'm using code first . and that solution doesn't look good .

Comment: @mohsen.d - If it is your code, might as well declare the type as `List<T>` (or, if this is not a good choice for you, do the cast where you need to `AddRange` to keep it localized - it is a very low cost operation).

Comment: No, no, no.  The reason this is an IList<T> to begin with is because it may be something else than a List<T> implementation.  Write an extension method as shown by BlackjacketMack if you really need an AddRange method.

Comment: No idea why this received so many upvotes as it will clearly throw something like `InvalidCastException` if used on anything other than `List<T>` (array, for instance).

Comment: But, casting is not a good idea. It can lead to performance overhead.

Comment: Casting is not a good idea from the Interface point of view either.  If the object being cast is a Property or return value declared as IList<T>, there is no guarantee the object can be cast to List<T>.

Comment: Do not cast from IList to List because IList is not List.

Answer (score 104):

If you look at the [C# source code for List<T>](https://referencesource.microsoft.com/#mscorlib/system/collections/generic/list.cs,cf7f4095e4de7646), I think List<T>.AddRange() has optimizations that a simple loop doesn't address.  So, an extension method should simply check to see if the IList<T> is a List<T>, and if so use its native AddRange().

Poking around the source code, you see the .NET folks do similar things in their own LINQ extensions for things like .ToList() (if it is a list, cast it... otherwise create it).

```
public static class IListExtension
{
    public static void AddRange<T>(this IList<T> list, IEnumerable<T> items)
    {
        if (list == null) throw new ArgumentNullException(nameof(list));
        if (items == null) throw new ArgumentNullException(nameof(items));

        if (list is List<T> asList)
        {
            asList.AddRange(items);
        }
        else
        {
            foreach (var item in items)
            {
                list.Add(item);
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: From the optimization point of view, you are actually casting `list` to `List<T>` two times here. One of which could be optimized away with the `as` keyword.

Comment: Good call @bashis.  I always go back and forth on the cost of a double cast vs. GC cleanup of our new var.  But we could indeed do var listCasted = list as List<T>;  if(listCasted != null)...

Maybe c# 6 declaration expressions will change this pattern: if(myVar.As(out myVarCasted)) myVarCasted...)

Comment: Can you update the code with the optimization mentioned? I am not as fluent in the newest features yet. @BlackjacketMack

Comment: @zuckerthoben - I just ran a test iterating one million iterations using both approaches and there was no difference in performance.  So I wouldn't call it an optimization...additionally, it adds a line of code (but reduces a parens casting).  Anyhow, I probably would use 'as' these days:  var listCasted = list as List<T>;  if(listCasted != null){listCasted.AddRange(items);}.  Not worth updating the answer IMHO, but good to introduce as a syntactical alternative.

Comment: As of now you can do `if (list is List<T> castedList) { castedList.AddRange(items); }`

Comment: You can generalize the extension to ICollection<T>.

Answer (score 27):

You could do something like this:

```
IList<string> oIList1 = new List<string>{"1","2","3"};
IList<string> oIList2 = new List<string>{"4","5","6"};
IList<string> oIList3 = oIList1.Concat(oIList2).ToList();
```

So, basically you would use the `Concat()` extension and `ToList()` to get a similar functionality as `AddRange()`.

[Source](http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en/csharpgeneral/thread/7a081b9d-7617-4432-829a-5b7548de5dab)

Comment: The problem with your approach is that `Enumerable.Concat` is implemented by `System.Linq.Enumerable` and that method's return value is `IEnumerable<TSource>`, so I believe it shouldn't be cast back to `IList<TSource>` - it might return something else due to implementation details that we don't know without checking the source code - even though, there's no guarantee it won't change - so special attention must be taken when supporting multiple .NET versions.

Answer (score 11):

You could also write an extension method like this:

```
internal static class EnumerableHelpers
{
    public static void AddRange<T>(this IList<T> collection, IEnumerable<T> items)
    {
        foreach (var item in items)
        {
            collection.Add(item);
        }
    }
}
```

Usage:

```cs
IList<int> collection = new MyCustomList(); //Or any other IList except for a fixed-size collection like an array
var items = new[] {1, 4, 5, 6, 7};
collection.AddRange(items);
```

Which is still iterating over items, but you don't have to write the iteration or cast every time you call it.

Answer (score 4):

Another answer using LINQ, provided the thing you're adding is a `List<T>` or you are able to call `ToList()` on it:

```
IEnumerable<string> toAdd = new string[] {"a", "b", "c"};
IList<string> target = new List<string>();

toAdd.ToList().ForEach(target.Add);
```

Answer (score 1):

IList don't has AddRange() ,but  has Concat() which combine yours collection

Comment: it would be better to add a code sample to make you answer more useful

Comment: `IList<T>.Concat(IEnumerable<T>)` returns the concatenated sequence as an enumerable so leaves the list untouched. That may or may not be the desired result.