# How to add a new List row to an IList within an IList

Tags: c#, list

I'm having trouble updating an IList within an IList with a new row of data. Both Add() and AddRange() are not working out.

Please excuse my clumsy attempt to describe the landscape I'm working with.

```
public class DetailViewModel
{
    public int id { get; set; }
    public decimal qualScore { get; set; }
    public int testCount { get; set; }
    public string qualRating { get; set; }
    public IList<QCheckList> qualCheck { get; set; }

}

public class QCheckList
{
    public int printOrder { get; set; }
    public string description{ get; set; }
    public int? value { get; set; }
    public string grade { get; set; }
}
```

In the controller I have

```
vm = new DetailViewModel();
// other code here to read data from the DB into vm, then later...
List<QCheckList> Qual1 = calc.qualifyMark(score, subject);
```

The method qualityMark() returns a List of type QCheckList.

I then want to write Qual1 to the qualCheck IList in the vm IList and have tried (unsuccessfully) both:

- `vm.qualCheck.AddRange(Qual1);`  error says IList<QCheckList> does not contain a definition for AddRange
- `vm.qualCheck.Add(Qual1);` error says System.Collections.Generic.List<Objects.ViewModels.QCheckList> to Objects.ViewModels.QCheckList

Neither of those errors make sense to me but they probably do to one of you. Can you please explain (for a dummy like me) how to fix this so the results of the method are added to the qualCheck IList in vm.  Thanks

Comment: Thank you both for your responses. I ended up using  ```return new QCheckList (){ printOrder = 1,  description = "textHere", value = 5, grade = "gradeHere"};``` 
The comment about naming standards is valid - I'm a very inexperienced codes, so will read through that info to try to improve.

Answer (score 0):

`IList` doesn't contain a definition for `AddRange`.  And you cannot use `Add` and pass a `List<T>` to it.

So you can fix this by something like

```
foreach(var item in Qual1)
    vm.qualCheck.Add(item);
```

You could also simply write an extension method:

```
static class ListExtensions
{
    static public void Add<T>(this IList<T> me, params T[] items)
    {
        foreach (T item in items)
        {
            me.Add(item);
        }
    }
}
```

And that should allow your code to work using simply `Add`.  LINQ uses extension methods heavily under the covers to do what it does.

Comment: Note: It is good idea to optimize for `List<T>` as shown in [duplicate](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13158121/how-to-add-a-range-of-items-to-an-ilist) I picked.

Comment: @AlexeiLevenkov Agree 100%.  Use better performance when possible.  I'd edit but no reason to with the dupe mark afaik.

Answer (score 0):

```
vm = new DetailViewModel();
List<QCheckList> Qual1 = calc.qualifyMark(score, subject);

foreach(var checkList in Qual1){
    vm.qualCheck.Add(checkList);
}
```

Also please review the C# naming conventions here https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/fundamentals/coding-style/coding-conventions

`Properties` for example `qualCheck` should be **Capitalized**

`local variables` for example `Qual1` should not.