# How to work with get-only ILists in the Azure SDK for C#

Tags: c#, azure, azure-sdk-.net

This ties in a lot to questions like [*How to add a range of items to an IList?*](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13158121/how-to-add-a-range-of-items-to-an-ilist), where some of the answers might be useful. However, I'm interested in an actual usecase and how the maintainers intend for the SDK to be used in the right way.

I am trying to create a virtual network using the [azure-sdk-for-net](https://github.com/Azure/azure-sdk-for-net).

The [sample](https://github.com/Azure/azure-sdk-for-net/blob/main/sdk/network/Azure.ResourceManager.Network/samples/Sample1_ManagingVirtualNetworks.md) works with hardcoded array expression initializers, but I have data arriving from some other source and need to construct [`VirtualNetworkData`](https://github.com/Azure/azure-sdk-for-net/blob/Azure.ResourceManager.Network_1.1.1/sdk/network/Azure.ResourceManager.Network/src/Generated/VirtualNetworkData.cs) from that incoming data.

As far as I have seen, this is an issue with all lists in the SDK.

This is what the sample does:

```
var data = new VirtualNetworkData
{
    DhcpOptionsDnsServers = { "1", "2" }
}
```

From what I can decipher, this syntax somehow calls the `Add` method on the `IList` interface.

This approach won't work for me, as I have data that I need to build and manage on the fly.

This is not allowed, since `DhcpOptionsDnsServers` only exposes a getter:

```
var myDnsServers = new List<string> { "1", "2" };
var data = new VirtualNetworkData
{
    // CS0200: Property or indexer 'VirtualNetworkData.DhcpOptionsDnsServers' cannot be assigned to -- it is read only
    DhcpOptionsDnsServers = myDnsServers
}
```

This error gave me the (probably bad) idea to extend the interface backing this property:

```
var myDnsServers = new List<string> { "1", "2" };
var data = new VirtualNetworkData
{
    // CS1503: Argument 1: cannot convert from 'string[]' to 'string'
    DhcpOptionsDnsServers = { myDnsServers.ToArray() }
};
```

With this extension, the above works but it feels like I violate all sorts of best practices.

```cs
internal static class CollectionExtension
{
    public static void Add(this ICollection<string> list, string[] range)
    {
        range.ToList().ForEach(r => list.Add(r));
    }
}
```

And lastly, one option is this:

```
var myDnsServers = new List<string> { "1", "2" };
var data = new VirtualNetworkData();
myDnsServers.ForEach(dns => data.DhcpOptionsDnsServers.Add(dns));

// Or concat
data.DhcpOptionsDnsServers.concat(myDnsServers);
```

I don't particularly like any of the options, but how I am supposed to work with the SDK and lists properly?

Comment: A simple foreach loop that calls the `Add` method. Simple and readable. A `ForEach` also works, but I (personal preference) generally prefer the simple loop as it is easier to interpret and debug.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the Azure SDK for C#, some properties that expose lists, such as `DhcpOptionsDnsServers` in the `VirtualNetworkData` class, are designed to be read-only.

And you cannot assign a new list to them but can only add elements to the existing list.
This helps to prevent overwrites of important configuration data.

To work with such read-only lists, you can add elements to the existing list using the Add method, as you have already shown in your last example:

```
var myDnsServers = new List<string> { "1", "2" };
var data = new VirtualNetworkData();
myDnsServers.ForEach(dns => data.DhcpOptionsDnsServers.Add(dns));
```

And also you can use the `Concat` method to add elements from another list to the existing list

```
var myDnsServers = new List<string> { "1", "2" };
var data = new VirtualNetworkData();
data.DhcpOptionsDnsServers = data.DhcpOptionsDnsServers.Concat(myDnsServers).ToList();
```

Both of these approaches are safe to use, as they work with the intended behaviour of the SDK and ensure that you do not accidentally overwrite existing configuration data.

Comment: Thanks for the response! But wouldn't using `IReadOnlyList` and allowing `init` achieve the same thing but it would be easier to create the object?

Comment: Yes, that's correct! If the VirtualNetworkData class used IReadOnlyList<string> instead of IList<string> for the DhcpOptionsDnsServers property, and marked it with the init keyword, you would be able to assign the list on initialization but not modify it afterwards.

Comment: @jokarl not per se. If you assume all methods inherit from a `List<T>` and remain that way then it could be implemented like that. But what if they use their own implementation of an `IList<T>`, which they almost certainly did? An example could be a custom `Add` method that performs validation.